# Smashoperator for the vertical space?

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, math-operators, mathtools

I would like to vertically smash a summation sign in a way that the line has a vertical space as if the summation sign wouldn't be there.

To illustrate it please see the MWE. The space between the first and second line should be the same as the space between the third and fourth line. At the moment it looks like the second line doesn't belong to the first one.

Note: I cannot write the last column into one line, because the second column will contain more text in the end and I have to break the last column into two or multiple lines.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{alignat}{3}
        &   \sum_{m \in M}  x_m     && = 1      & \quad &   , \forall m \in M \colon a \neq b ;                     \notag  \\
        &                                                                   &&              &               &   \phantom{,{}}   c \neq d                                                                \\
        &                                                       x_m     && = 1      &               &   , \forall m \in M \colon e \neq f ;                     \notag  \\
        &                                                                   &&              &               &   \phantom{,{}}   g \neq h            
\end{alignat}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `\smash[b]`:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{alignat}{2}
\smash[b]{\sum_{m \in M}}\, x_m &= 1\quad && , \forall m \in M \colon a \neq b ; \notag \\
                                &         && \phantom{,{}}   c \neq d \\
               x_m              &= 1      && , \forall m \in M \colon e \neq f ; \notag  \\
                                &         && \phantom{,{}}   g \neq h
\end{alignat}
\end{document}
```

Instead of `\,` you could use

```
\mathop{\smash[b]{\sum_{m \in M}}}
```

but it's more complicated with no real advantage other than inserting the thin space automatically.

I'd not left align `x_m`, but if you really want, you know how to do it.

Instead of the phantoms you could add another set of columns.

[image]

Note that using `\smash` alone would also remove the height, which is not desired here.

Comment: Thank you also for the other useful suggestions, it really looks better with the right aligned `x_m`

Comment: I've noticed that you use an additional `\,` after the braces of the smash command. For `smash` it seems to be necessary to add it. Is it also necessary in the case of the `smashoperator` command? It seems to be to much space when adding the `\,` then?

Comment: @user2653422 `\smash` produces an ordinary atom, whereas `\mathop` an Op atom. The latter adds automatically `\,` when it's followed by an ordinary atom (`x_m` in this case). If you use the `\mathop` way, then `\,` should be omitted.

Comment: So `\smashoperator` uses `\mathop` internally? The question about `\smashoperator` is not directly related to my question of the initial post and the result I wanted to achieve there, but about the spacing.

Comment: @user2653422 Sorry, but I see no `\smashoperator` in my answer. Are you referring to `mathtools`? It has a `\smashoperator`, but it does a completely different thing.

Comment: You are right I should have added a bit more information. It has to do with mathtools yes. Let's say I write `\smashoperator{\sum_{m \in M}}\, x_m`. Is it correct or should I go with `\smashoperator{\sum_{m \in M}} x_m`?

Comment: @user2653422 I'm not into using it, to be honest. Matter of taste, I think: do as it seems best to you. In this answer's code it's necessary for the reason I explained before.

Answer (score 3):

One way is to add some negative vertical space.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{alignat}{3}
        &   \sum_{m \in M}  x_m     && = 1      & \quad &   , \forall m \in M \colon a \neq b ;                     \notag  \\[-4\jot]    %%% <--- here
        &                                                                   &&              &               &   \phantom{,{}}   c \neq d                                                                \\
        &                                                       x_m     && = 1      &               &   , \forall m \in M \colon e \neq f ;                     \notag  \\
        &                                                                   &&              &               &   \phantom{,{}}   g \neq h
\end{alignat}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Another way is to smash.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{alignat}{3}
        &   \smash{\sum_{m \in M}}{}  x_m     && = 1      & \quad &   , \forall m \in M \colon a \neq b ;                     \notag  \\
        &                                                                   &&              &               &   \phantom{,{}}   c \neq d                                                                \\
        &                                                       x_m     && = 1      &               &   , \forall m \in M \colon e \neq f ;                     \notag  \\
        &                                                                   &&              &               &   \phantom{,{}}   g \neq h
\end{alignat}
\end{document}
```

[image]